# Unable to play MP4 files on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vlc, mp4

Because I could not find answer to my question, I am raising it here in the forum.

I have Acer Aspire One 722 and installed on it Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I downloaded MP4 files from GoPro yesterday and cannot play them in VLS or Media Player.

VLS - picture freezed and does not catch up with sound.
Video player - picture moves(slower that reality), but no accompnying sounds.

I installed extras as well as reinstalled VLS. nothing helps.

File is not corrupted as it works well on Windows.

Please, help! I would appreciate detailed advise.

Comment: Try to open the file with VLC in terminal and provide use the output. Open the terminal using (Ctrl + Alt + T) type vlc and then the path to your video. Ex: vlc /home/Talie/Videos/my_video.mp4